# How to make alert message with modal bootstrap in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

when I click modal button is like this.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" name="button" title="Hapus" method="get" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal{{$objek->id}}" onclick="javascript: {{url('/admin/objek/'.$objek->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```

and my modal like this.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal{{$objek->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Hapus Objek Wisata</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
         Hapus data objek wisata dengan nama {{$objek->nama_objek}}?
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form class="" action="{{url('/admin/objek', $objek->id)}}" method="post">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Tidak">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="name" value="Hapus">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is how to show modal bootstrap with alert message after page reload?

alert message like this, but I want to make this in modal bootstrap like when I click modal delete button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data has been submitted");</script>
```

thank for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session data` to make the modal open on the page reload.

After submitting the request just add some variable to session like this:

```
return redirect('route')->with('show_modal', true);
```

In `view.blade.php`:

```
<scirpt>
    $(function(){
        var show_modal = "{{ session()->pull('show_modal') }}";

        if(typeof show_modal !== 'undefined' && show_modal) {
            $('#modalId').modal('show');
            // This will open up the modal if the variable is present in session as true
            // OR you can simply show an alert message!
            alert("Data has been submitted");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, but this way is still not work. any else solution?

Comment: I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: when I place button modal in page index, the modal is work with clicked button. but I want to make the modal show first in page index without clicked the button. like alert message before page show.

Comment: The error `$ is not defined` is due to the unavailability of the jquery library in your code, and the answer for your second question is no, you can't make that happen with the modal as alerts works! Hope you understand the issue clearly!